# Magento customer import programmatically without e-mail address

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, import

I am inserting customer data in magento programmatically; for my client, email is not a mandatory field, so some users will not have it.

When I insert the customer without email, it throws an error "email is a required field" .

### code

```
$customer = $this->_getCustomerModel();
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$userid = Mage::helper('customer')->CreateUserid(Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data::LAWYER);

$customer->setFirstname($_customer->getFirstname());
$customer->setLastname($_customer->getLastname());
$customer->setGroupId(Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data::LAWYER);
if($_customer->getEmail()!='')
{
    $customer->setIsSubscribed(1);
    $customer->setEmail($_customer->getEmail());
}
$customer->setUserid($userid);
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->setConfirmation(null);
$customer->save();
```

Is it possible to insert the data in customer table without email?

Comment: you can remove the required option in db for customer email

Comment: ya i did,but still i can't able to insert the customer data with out email id.do you have any other idea or suggestion

Comment: just generate a random email for each! Email is in fact used as frontend login, you know.

Comment: except to generate the random email id, do you have any other idea,because i having nearly 10 lakhs record for that nearly 5 lakhs user don't have a email id, if i generate random email id it make some duplicate problem,that is why i asking some other idea and suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the import without an email address. It's the main identifier and used to detect existing entries. In fact, I doubt any part of Magento will allow customers to be inserted without an email address.